# Can motherboards heal themselves or should I be worried?

Tags: motherboard

Here is the whole story. I left my niece, 3, and my nephew, 1 and a half, alone with my computer for five minutes they were fooling around with it and when I got back, I saw it had shut down. I tried turning it on; nothing. I tried to figure out what was wrong and **I found a dime on the motherboard** (well technically it wasn't a dime since it's euro currency. it was more like 10 cents of a euro). Basically what happen is they were fighting for the mouse and the coin fell in. I tried turning it on again the fan was spinning full speed as it usually does at boot time but the monitor wasn't turning on and the fan kept spinning and spinning.

I was actually worried a readying myself to purchase another Biostar A68N-5600 motherboard (which is the current motherboard I am using) hoping that if the motherboard was the issue windows 8.1 won't notice the difference and everything would be fine.

I still had to know what was the issue: was is the motherboard or some other hardware (HDD, RAM, USB peripherals, etc.) connected to it that prevented it from working properly. So while I was looking for a new mobo I disconnected the audio interface (Focusrite Scarlett Solo 2nd Gen) and connected it to the laptop computer. And the audio interface wasn't working either (no LED was turning on).

I tried turning on the Biostar motherboard once again **and it worked**  And so I was left with a damaged audio interface and Focusrite would on repair or replace it if it was not working due to a manufacturing fault. which wasn't the case.

And I was there wondering why the audio interface wasn't shutting down my laptop or something (since it was preventing my Biostar mother A68N-5600. Guess what!? it was working fine. So I checked everything else. Windows shows 8GB of RAM, every HDDs works fine, same goes for bluetooth, wifi and every peripherals connected to USB.

**That's why I'm here**: Should I be worried? is there something wrong waiting to happen? can a computer just fix itself on its own? By the way the motherboard has a "Super Anti-Surge Protection", could it be the reason why nothing is wrong with the computer or any of its components and peripherals?

Comment: So does the audio interface work fine now too? It's unclear in this part: "*I was there wondering why the audio interface wasn't shutting down my laptop or something (since it was preventing my Biostar mother A68N-5600. Guess what!?* ***it was working fine."*** - And how is your computer arranged such that a coin (or anything else) falling off a table can go right inside the case & land on the motherboard? Are there no walls, or vent covers on your computer?

Comment: @Xen2050 Yeah the Audio interface as well is working fine! About the computer case... Don't laugh but my motherboard is just inside a cardboard box :). I am not gonna waste money in buying a huge and bulky computer case (which is cheaper than the HTPC computer case my motherboard actually needs).

Comment: Cardboard can work, if you're careful and don't have toddlers around, or pets, or high humidity... you should probably look for a metal case, even an old one from 5 years ago, or 10, or 20, or 30 years ago that's big enough should be customizable & an upgrade from your box (or just put your box inside it, plus some fans), and old cases are often very cheap or free

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, hardware in general doesn't "fix" it self. However, it could get into an undefined or 'blocked' state due to a short circuit. That's why a total power-down sometimes helps.

In your case the audio device is probably fried and prevented your motherboard from booting; your laptop may have better USB ports.

Anti-surge protection usually only applies to external ports (USB ports, audio, network, etc) that might get a 'zap' from static discharge or lightning; it can't protect against a coin inside the computer case.

Either way, your motherboard may be fine, or still fail next week; it's hard to tell.

Comment: if it fails next week, will it damage any of the other hardware connected to it (HDDs and USB devices)?

Comment: Very unlikely. These kind of failures usually mean some part inside a chip stops working and that's it.

Comment: You were right the mobo failed me after all!

Answer (score 2):

@JvO answer is incorrect.

In your specific case - [the motherboard features OC/OV/OH protection](http://www.biostar-usa.com/app/en-us/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=894) which protects your motherboard from "damage when doing overclock or an unusual current import" - which is what saved you.  IE the "super anti surge protection" you talk about is exactly what protected your motherboard.

In general - quite a lot of decent hardware does have protections and fix themselves.  I remember power supplies 25 years ago requiring a shutoff period before they would fire up again (in the days that computers had physical on/off switches - after they were shorted or abuse.

[Resettable fuses / thermistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse) are not new or expensive and are designed to protect inputs which are exposed to overcurrent, and are common on decent equipment.  As these "blow" (or get high resistance) when they heat up due to overcurrent, waiting a short time for them to cool down "fixes" the fuses - provided you don't make a habit of throwing metal into your motherboard **your motherboard should be just fine.**

Comment: Interesting read (especially the wikipedia article). I've got to say, you sold me there! that definitely sounds like what happened to my computer. Not (fully) working for a certain time then as the resistance goes down it starts working back again. Nice!

Comment: I take it back, 1-3 days after your answer the motherboard crashed the computer again. And the motherboard worked intermittently! I had to buy another one.